# why json not show empty array in there no it in node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

i make a demo of xsl transform.here is my demo .I try to transform this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
    <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>


</catalog>
```

http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLs/1

I convert the xml output to json using this link
http://convertjson.com/xml-to-json.htm
I get this output

```
{
   "videos": {
      "video": [
         {
            "t": "Empire Burlesque",
            "to": "Bob Dylan"
         },
         {
            "t": "Empire Burlesque",
            "to": "Bob Dylan"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

but when i try to parse this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>

</catalog>
```

http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuPu

then try to convert my xml out this in json 
output xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><videos/>
```

it gives me this

```
{
   "videos": ""
}
```

**why it is not giving or expected output**

```
{
   "videos": []
}
```

can we add condition in `xslt` transform if there is no item in `videos` than it will not create?

Comment: It's because you always output at least an empty `<video />` element from your XSLT...?

Comment: Your xslt code should really be posted here with the question.

Comment: That conversion tool apparently just works that way. The input XML is just `<videos/>`, and that's apparently what it gives you for a self-closed tag. There's no single canonical way to represent XML as JSON.

Comment: can we add condition if there no videos the it will not create video tag

Comment: can we add condition in `xslt` transform if there is no item in `videos` than it will not create?